# Convergence $ \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}}$$
But when I plugged it in to any online calculator, It said it couldn't find the integral and that it might not exist. Does this integral converge or is it just very hard to evaluate? Furthermore, If it can be evaluated, I would appreciate any help evaluating it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't exist, as the integrand blows up as $1/(1 \pm x)$ at the endpoints of the integration interval.

Comment: There is nothing to be solved about integrals, the integral exists,  The integral might not converge though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_\limits{x\to 1^-}\left(1-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)=-\infty$, so the square root isn’t even defined over the whole interval. And even taking its absolute value wouldn’t help, since it blows up.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @LukeSequeira: You’re welcome!

Comment: I like this answer being concise. I may be a bit pedantic: we don't need an integrand having definitions over the whole interval but only "most" of the interval; "blowing up" is not sufficient for having the problematic improper integral as the example $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}\;dx$ shows.

Answer (score 1):

To add a few words to Brian's answer, the integrand of the "integral" you want to "solve" is not *defined* "almost everywhere" on the interval $(-1,1)$. So the question is not well-defined.

Here is the graph of the function $\displaystyle f(x)=1-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^2}$ on $(-1,1)$:

[image]

However, one can ask whether the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{f(x)}\;dx$ is convergent or not.